# Consuming from multiple Kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to write a Kafka application that consumes from topics and save something in a database. The topics are created by Debezium Kafka connect based on mysql binlog. So I have one topic per table.
This is the code I am using for consuming from one topic:

```java
KStream<GenericRecord,mysql.company.tiers.Envelope>[] tierStream = builder.stream("mysql.alopeyk.tiers",
                Consumed.with(TierSerde.getGenericKeySerde(), TierSerde.getEnvelopeSerde()));
```

From architectural point of view I should create a KStream for each table and run them in parallel. But the number of tables is so big and having that amount of threads may not be the best option.

All the tables have a column called created_at (it is a laravel app) so I am curious if there is a way to have a generic Serde for values that extracts this common column. This is the only column I am interested in its value besides the name of the table.

Comment: `But the number of tables is so big and having that amount of threads may not be the best option.` -- what do you mean by  this? The number of thread only depends on your config `num.stream.threads` (cf. http://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#num-stream-threads)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax my intention was to have one thread per topic in my application. And since there is one topic for each table it would be lots of threads.

Comment: This is not the best config you can have. (1) KTables are sharded based on the table input topic partitions and parallel processing happens based on tasks (that are determined by input topic partitions -- for joins, one task will map to one partition _per topic_) (check out `Topology#describe()` and `KafkaStreams#localThreadMetatdata()` got get more insights). (2) If you join all those tables, a single thread will access _all_ tables (ie, one shard per table) to process a single input record. (3) You should configure the number of threads based on the number of cores you client machine has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about how your value is serialized by the applicatino that produced messages (Connector).
If `Deserializer` (`Serdes`) can extract `created_at` from different type of messages it is possible.

So, the Answer is yes, but it depends on your message value nad `Deserializer`.

Assuming all your messages after serialization have format as follow:

- create_at;name:position;...
- create_at;city,country;...
- create_at;product_name;...

In such case `Deserializer` needs only to take characters till first `;` and cast it to date and the rest of value can be dropped.

Sample code:

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        String strDate = new String(data);
        return new Date(Long.parseLong(strDate.substring(0, strDate.indexOf(";"))));
    }
}
```